Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart' after adding flutter_gen
Background

I'm using flutter_localizations to localize my app.
I'm using build_runner for generating files. (riverpod, freezed etc).

pubspec.yaml
...

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  intl: 0.18.1

...

dev_dependencies:
  build_runner: ^2.4.8
  flutter_gen: ^5.4.0

...

flutter:
  generate: true

...


l10n.yaml
arb-dir: lib/l10n
template-arb-file: app_en.arb
output-localization-file: app_localizations.dart

some_widget.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart';

class SomeWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const SomeWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(AppLocalizations.of(context).someText);
  }
}

Problem
flutter_gen is the issue. I must add package: flutter_gen to the dev dependency.

Why I must add this
After implementing localization according to the official Flutter Doc, running the command dart run build_runner build causes an error (Bad state: Unable to generate package graph). This is discussed here. It was solved by adding flutter_gen.

Adding flutter_gen causes issues
Files containing l10n code such as: AppLocalizations.of(context).someText raises an error: Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart' on import line 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart';. This is explained here. Simplified, flutter creates the l10n generated files under a fake package name under flutter_gen which conflicts with the real flutter_gen added under dev dependency.


What I tried

Restarting VS Code, restarting Dart analyzer.

flutter clean, other various deleting cache methods.


I'm looking for a solution where I can import AppLocalizations without errors and I can run build_runner commands without error.

Since generating under a fake package name flutter_gen causes the issue, it can be prevented by changing the generated file output location to your source code (under the lib/ folder).
Change:
l10n.yaml
arb-dir: lib/l10n
template-arb-file: app_en.arb
output-localization-file: app_localizations.g.dart # <-- The location where it's generated. Doesn't have to be a `.g.dart`.
output-dir: lib/l10n/generated
synthetic-package: false # <-- We won't reference l10n stuff by the fake package name anymore.

some_widget.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:<project_name>/l10n/generated/app_localizations.g.dart';

class SomeWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const SomeWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(AppLocalizations.of(context).someText);
  }
}


this fixed it for me , thank you <3

Try running this command if the above answer doesn't work for you.
flutter gen-l10n 

